# Using Git (SSH) in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: git, visual-studio, ssh, visual-studio-2017

Is it possible to use Git via ssh in Visual Studio 2017?

I need to use Auth via ssh key.

Comment: yes it is possible to use  git with Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio 2017 Git SSH support is only partial, you cannot clone but you can perform most other 'normal' git operations. [Apparently they do plan to add clone support at some point.](https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/03/vs2017-git)

You can clone a repository using git bash, and then open the project in VS and the git functionality should work.

For documentation on this see [this article](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate) - it's TFS specific for steps 1 & 2, however step 3 is applicable regardless of the Git web server implementation you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

I am currently using it: I am using `pageant.exe` to load the ssh keys, and I am using Visual Studio 2017 to pull/push. And all works well.

(PS. it VS2015 does not support ssh git protocol, it only comes within VS2017)